# SQLite returning min value greater than max value

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to query a database of accounts, each of which has multiple entries, and pull the total, average, min, max, and count from each account.  The code below is an example for one account.  The problem is I get many entries where the minimum value is greater than the maximum.  I've spot-checked some of these accounts and it looks like the average is being calculated correctly, so I don't think it's an issue of the datatype.  Could it be the leading '1' in 11 is read as smaller than the 9?  If so, how do i fix this?

```
SELECT  `Account` ,
    --`CustomerName` ,
    `METER_SIZE` ,
    SUM(`Consumption`) AS `Total_Cons` ,
    AVG(`Consumption`) AS `Avg_Cons` ,
    MIN(`Consumption`) AS `Min_Cons` ,
    MAX(`Consumption`)  AS `Max_Cons` ,
    COUNT(`Consumption`) AS `Bills` 
FROM `Billing_Meterreads_2015_2017`
WHERE `CustomerClass` LIKE 'Residential' 
    AND `Account` LIKE '000000280' ;
```

Returns

```
|Account   | METER_SIZE | Total_Cons | Avg_Cons | Min_Cons | Max_Cons | Bills |
|000000280 | 3/4        | 597.0      | 7.6538   |11.00000  | 9.00000  | 78    |
```

Comment: Please show some sample table data and also show us the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check what datatype `Consumption` is. You are probably right assuming it's a type issue and `Consumption` is a string where '11.00000' < '9.0000', because '1' < '9'.

`AVG` may be working, because there is no average on strings, so SQLite converts to numbers silently.

Possible solutions:

- Good: Change the column's datatype.
- Less good: `min(cast(consumtion as decimal))`, `max(cast(consumtion as decimal))`

Comment: EXCELLENT!  Due to SQLite's inability to modify columns or alter tables, I'm using the "Less Good" approach for now.  Great to know the underlying issue here.  Thank you!!